# Change color of TAniIndicator

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

In Delphi 10.2 Tokyo I use a `TAniIndicator` until the database is loaded.

By default, the color of the bubble is **black**. I would like to change it to be **white** without creating a `Style`. I haven't found any property for that.

Is there any way to change it?

Comment: Add a style book and edit the style of the compoent. You can find a lot of examples online

Comment: Yes, but that's a little different with the AniIndicator, I didn't see the detail of the component ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like this (for default style), note that you'll need to improve `ReplaceBlackColor` function to make bubble completely white

```
procedure ReplaceBlackColor(const ABitmap: TBitmap);
var
  I, J: Integer;
  M: TBitmapData;
  C: PAlphaColorRec;
begin
  if ABitmap.Map(TMapAccess.ReadWrite, M) then
  try
    for J := 0 to ABitmap.Height - 1 do
      for I := 0 to ABitmap.Width - 1 do
      begin
        C := @PAlphaColorArray(M.Data)[J * (M.Pitch div 4) + I];
        if C^.Color = TAlphaColorRec.Black then
          C^.Color := TAlphaColorRec.White;
      end;
  finally
    ABitmap.Unmap(M);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  bla: TBitmapListAnimation;
begin
  bla := AniIndicator1.FindStyleResource('ani') as TBitmapListAnimation;
  ReplaceBlackColor(bla.AnimationBitmap);
end;
```

Comment: So you're about to click that button for every frame :)?

Comment: @Victoria All frames are in single bitmap.

Comment: Thank you! Didn't know that (and it was merely a bad joke, I haven't expected that `AnimationBitmap` with no index would be a single frame). I was checking how to modify `FFill` member from outside (as it's being set in control's `ApplyStyle` method), but no luck. I have a very limited experience with FMX.

Answer (score 4):

Add a `TFillRGBEffect` to the indicator control and set its `Color` property to desired color.

`TFillRGBEffect`, like other effects, will apply to any controls "below" it, so you can repaint whole UI in just one go.